# SELECT Queries in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database consisting of two tables, Individuals & Pairs. Individuals consists two columns; 'Bird_ID' and 'Parents_Pair_number' and Pairs consists of three columns; 'Pair', 'Female_ID' and 'Male_ID'. 'Parents_Pair_number' and 'Pair' have a Many-to-one relationship. Via this relation one can check the parents of an individual.

But now I was thinking of making automatized family trees using a form. My plan was to make a field (Bird_ID_Field) in which you can find a certain individual and that other fields such as Father, Mother, Fathers father etc. etc. would auto-fill based on that entry.

I tried to auto-fill the Father_ID (Field) using the following VBA code:

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strBird_ID As String
If Bird_ID_Field <> "" Then
strBird_ID = Bird_ID_Field
strSQL = "SELECT Pairs.[Male_ID] " & _
         "FROM Pairs " & _
         "WHERE PAIR = (SELECT Individuals.[Parents_Pair_number] FROM Individuals WHERE Individuals.[Bird_ID]= '" & strBird_ID & "');"

DoCmd.OpenQuery strSQL

Father_ID = strSQL
End If
```

But after updating the Bird_ID_Field I get the following error: Microsoft Access can't find the object ''.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Thanks in forward!
Jeroen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use recordsets:

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

If Nz(Bird_ID_Field,"") <> "" Then
    strBird_ID = Nz(Bird_ID_Field, "")
    strSQL = "SELECT Pairs.[Male_ID] " & _
             "FROM Pairs " & _
             "WHERE PAIR = (SELECT Individuals.[Parents_Pair_number] FROM Individuals WHERE Individuals.[Bird_ID]= '" & strBird_ID & "');"

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Father_ID = rst![Male_ID]
    End If
End If

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

And also I would recommend to use `JOIN` for tables joining instead of subquery.